# Rendering Time of Image Defined in Xaml

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, time, rendering

I have a problem about displaying Image on Screen.

I created new WPF project in VS2010 and added the following code in MainWindow.xaml.

```
<Window
   ...>
   <Grid>
     <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.jpg">
     </Grid.Background>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

But displaying image.jpg is not that fast as I expected, and It doesn't show image.jpg immediately.

First it shows Empty Screen for a while(during rendering time, I think) and after that shows image.jpg.

How can I avoid the Empty Screen.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ImageSource.DownloadCompleted` event, `PriorityBinding` and `Binding.IsAsync` will help you here...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/b3dc9baa-4cf6-49ed-a316-b9fb1cd29516